Download file Via web view
hello i have a problem try to download files from webview app with this way
private void startDownload(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype) {
    // Create a DownloadManager request     
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));      
    request.setMimeType(mimetype);     
    request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);     
    request.setDescription("Downloading file...");     
    request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype));     
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();     
    request.setNotificationVisibility( DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);     
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir( Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype));      // Enqueue the download    
    DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);     
    downloadManager.enqueue(request);      
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
}

and this is how backend site works to take url. After a lot of tries i just started the download from download manager but without success it fail at 0% i think doesn't take the url just take the name and add it to download manager because on source i have download file...
app.get('/download/:filePath', (req, res) => {
    // Decode the file path
    const decodedPath = decodeURIComponent(req.params.filePath);
    
    // Construct the full path
    const fullPath = path.join('D:\\', decodedPath);

    // Log the full path
    console.log('Attempting to access file at:', fullPath);

    // Check if the file exists and has read permissions
    fs.access(fullPath, fs.constants.R_OK, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('File not found or access error:', err);
            if (!res.headersSent) {
                res.status(404).json({ error: 'File not found' });
            }
            return;
        }

        res.download(fullPath, (downloadErr) => {
            if (downloadErr) {
                if (res.headersSent) {
                    console.error('Error during file download:', downloadErr);
                    return;
                }
                console.error('Error during file download:', downloadErr);
                res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error during file download' });
            } else {
                console.log('File successfully downloaded.');
            }
        });
    });
});


What error messages do you get on the client? And the server? What is logged?

the read credentials get from an sql server. when credentials read starts a session with vat as attribute each user see his folder from the server. In server i get fAttempting to access file at: D:\012345678\ΜΙΣΘΟΔΟΣΙΑ\Παραστατικά-5.jpg
File successfully downloaded. From browser downloads as should. From the app start download and immediately stops and all files has extention .html and the file may be jpg and as source i see downloading file... i think can't handle the url but is my first attempt for android. what you suggest to log from the device. i don't use emulator i am testing on device
